# Maven flyway Found non-empty schema(s) "PUBLIC" but no schema history table

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, flyway

I am just learning Spring Boot with Maven and I have encountered an error that I cannot resolve.
I have attached a dependency from Flyway and when I want to install it (I'm clicking install on Lifecycle), I get this error:

> Found non-empty schema(s) "PUBLIC" but no schema history table.
> Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.

What could be causing this and how to fix it?

I'm using Java 8 and my dependency with Flyway looks like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot is trying to run Flyway migrate as part of a maven goal it has configured.

> Found non-empty schema(s) "PUBLIC" but no schema history table.

The error message is stating that the default schema which Flyway is trying to run against, which is `PUBLIC`, is not empty. As a result, Flyway know needs to know what the state the database before it is able to create a schema history table and migrate.

> Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.

These are the two ways you can correct this by creating a baseline to build your migrations upon. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/baseline

In spring boot, baseline on migrate can be configured with `spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true`.

Additionally, `install` in Maven does not mean install the dependencies but builds and puts the build artifacts of your product in your `.m2` maven repository.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and clarification of the topic. I followed the instructions and the program worked.